# Как убрать прокрутку страницы при нажатии на показать еще?

Tags: html, css, jquery

Есть небольшой сайт, с небольшим количеством товаров, в мобильной версии нужно чтобы отображалось несколько товаров, но появлялась кнопка показать сделал все на display none. Есть код, но когда я нажимаю показать еще меня сразу перебрасывает на последний элемент, а мне нужно чтобы в каком месте страницы я кнопку нажал, в таком и остался, как сделать?

```
let state = 0;
$('.catalog__button').click(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    if(state == 0) {
        $('.catalog__mobile').show();
        $('.catalog__button').text('Скрыть');
        state ++;
    }
    else {
        $('.catalog__mobile').hide();
        $('.catalog__button').text('Посмотреть все');
        state --;
    }  
});
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1158901/275019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На `body` примените свойство `overflow-anchor`:

```
body {
  overflow-anchor: none;
}
```

Только учтите, что данное свойство не работает в IE и Safari.

**P.S.** Также я бы советовал отказаться в вашем примере от jQuery – данный функционал легко написать на нативном JavaScript, используя [classList API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) и метод `toggle` в частности: например, можно по клику переключать класс со свойством `display: none`.

Comment: спасибо большое)